# Can not click on a button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button using Selenium and Python, but I can not click it.

```html
<div id="environmentNavigation" class="yui-navset yui-navset-top">
    <ul class="yui-nav">
        <li nav="myDash" class="" title="">
            <a href="#" hidefocus="true">
                <em>My dashboard</em>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li nav="myApp">
            <a href="#" hidefocus="true">
                <em>My applications</em>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li nav="myPermits" class="" title="">
            <a href="#" hidefocus="true">
                <em>My permits</em>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li nav="allPermits" class="" title="">
            <a href="#" hidefocus="true">
                <em>All permits</em>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li nav="myDetails" class="selected" title="active">
            <a href="#" hidefocus="true">
                <em>My Details</em>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the HTML source. I want to click on the <kbd>All permits</kbd> button. I tried using XPath,link_text, but nothing worked. How can I fix it?

The website is confidential which requires login, so I can't share it.

Webdriver object:

```python
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
driver.get('https://myminesonline.business.qld.gov.au/suite/apps')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

Full XPath expression:

```python
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]'))).click()
```

XPath expression:

```python
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="environmentNavigation"]/ul/li[4]'))).click()
```

[image: Please see the image]

#### driver.page_source

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
  <title>My dashboard | Appian Application Portal</title>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/suite/portal/img/appian_16x16.ico?appian_environment=">
  <link rel="icon" href="/suite/portal/img/appian_48x48.png?appian_environment=" sizes="48x48">
  <link rel="icon" href="/suite/portal/img/appian_32x32.png?appian_environment=" sizes="32x32">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var hash = window.sessionStorage && sessionStorage.getItem(\'hash\');
    if (hash) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem(\'hash\');
      window.location = window.location + hash;
    }
    // Do not use h:rewrite or c:url because the path already
    // indicates the environment, and we don\'t want the
    // environment to show up in the address bar
    var envPath = \'/suite/apps\';

    // Validate browser URL is that of the current environment
    var envPathRegEx = /\\/suite\\/apps/i;
    var isAddressBarOk = !!top.location.href.match(envPathRegEx);
    if (!isAddressBarOk) {
      top.location.href = envPath;
      return;
    }

    // Validate that we don\'t try to load
    // index inside index (infinite loop)
    if (top != self) {
      var isTopIndex = !!top.fContent;  // Assume if there\'s fContent in
                                        // top, then top is index.jsp
      if (isTopIndex) {
        // index.jsp ended up nested in itself; default
        // to environment entry point
        top.fContent.location.href = \'/suite/portal/loadEnvironmentHome.do?appian_environment=apps\';
      } else {
        top.location.href = envPath;
      }
      return;
    }
  })();

  window.APPIAN = {
  };
  </script>

</head>

<frameset rows="*, 0" border="0">
  <frame name="fContent" id="fContent" src="/suite/portal/loadEnvironmentHome.do?appian_environment=apps" noresize="" title="Main Content Frame">
</frameset>
<noframes>
  This site requires frames. Please turn on frame support in your web browser.
</noframes>

</html>
```

It seems that the tag I require is not inside these. What should I do now?

Body tag copied from the inspect element

```html
<body class="yui-skin-sam" onload="if (typeof timeout == 'function') { timeout(); }" onbeforeunload="window.eventCache.flushAll();" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1002.0" data-gr-ext-installed=""><iframe id="_yuiResizeMonitor" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; width: 10em; height: 10em; top: -124px; left: -124px; border-width: 0px;"></iframe>

  <a id="skipNavigationLink508" href="#environmentContent">Jump to content</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.decorator = 'main';
    if (isIE) { $("body").addClass("isIE"); }
  </script>

  <div id="bodyDecoratorContainer">
    <iframe name="fProcess" id="fProcess" style="display:none;position:absolute;width:600px;height:400px;margin:100px;top:0;left:0px;z-index:100;" src="/suite/portal/blank.jsp" title="Background processing frame. No displayed content."></iframe>
    <iframe name="popupTarget" id="popupTarget" style="display:none;" src="/suite/portal/blank.jsp" title="Background processing frame. No displayed content."></iframe>

    <div id="mainContent" style="">
      <div id="environmentHeader">
        <div class="a1">
          <div class="b1">
                    <img src="/suite/portal/img/skins/default/app.gif" id="applicationIcon" alt="Application"></div>
                    <div class="b2 appName" id="applicationName" title="MyMinesOnline - Click here to view available applications"><a href="#" id="applicationNameLink">MyMinesOnline</a></div>
          <div class="b3">
      <div id="topNavItemsMenu" class="yuimenu yui-module yui-overlay" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
        <div class="bd">
          <ul class="first-of-type">
            <li topnavid="myminesonline" id="yui-gen0" class="yuimenuitem first-of-type" groupindex="0" index="0">
              <a href="#" title="" class="yuimenuitemlabel">
                MyMinesOnline
              </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="dividerContainer"><div class="menuDivider"></div></div>

         <ul class="first-of-type">
         <!-- Remove comments to re-enable dropdown items.
             <li topNavId="system.tasks" >
               <a href="#">
                 Tasks
               </a>
             </li>

             <li topNavId="system.alerts" >
               <a href="#">
                 Alerts
               </a>
             </li>
          -->

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

<script>
  (function(){
    YAHOO.widget.MenuManager.removeMenu(YAHOO.widget.MenuManager.getMenu('topNavItemsMenu'));
    var menu = new YAHOO.widget.Menu('topNavItemsMenu', {
      maxheight: 400,
      scrollincrement: 2,
      context: ["applicationNameLink",
                YAHOO.widget.Overlay.TOP_RIGHT,
                YAHOO.widget.Overlay.BOTTOM_RIGHT]
    });
    menu.hide();

    var showFn = function () {
      menu.render();
      menu.align();
      menu.show();
    }

    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener('applicationName', 'click', showFn, null, menu);

    var menuElements = $("#topNavItemsMenu li");
    for (var i = 0; i < menuElements.length; i++) {
      var menuItem = menuElements.get(i);
      YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(menuItem, 'click', function(){
        var topNavId = this.getAttribute('topNavId');
        ApplicationPortalUtils.loadTopNavigation(topNavId, ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem);
        return false;
      }, menuItem);
    }
  })();
</script></div>
  </div>
  <div class="a2">
    <div class="c1">
      <div class="d1">
      <!--    Remove comment tags to re-enable links.
        <a hidefocus="true" href="/suite/tempo" class="headerTempoIcon" title='Launch Tempo in new window' target="tempoWindow">Tempo</a>
        <a hidefocus="true" href="#" class="sprite inbox" onclick="ApplicationPortalUtils.loadTopNavigation('system.tasks', ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem); return false;">Tasks<span class="taskCount"></span></a>
        <a hidefocus="true" href="#" class="sprite alerts" onclick="ApplicationPortalUtils.loadTopNavigation('system.alerts', ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem); return false;">Alerts<span class="notificationCount"></span></a>
      -->
        <a hidefocus="true" href="#" class="sprite preferences" onclick="backgroundAction('/portal/updateUserPreferences.do','asiDialog');" title="Click to modify preferences">anitalee.ishere@yahoo.com</a>
      <!--
        <a hidefocus="true" href="https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/19.3" target="_blank" class="sprite help" title="Open User Guide in new window" hidefocus="hidefocus">Help</a>
      -->

        <a hidefocus="true" href="#" class="sprite logout" onclick="logout();">Sign Out</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c2">

      <a id="logo" href="#" onclick="return false;"><img src="/suite/portal/img/skins/default/companylogo.png" height="31px" alt="MyMinesOnline"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearboth"></div>
</div>

<script>
  (function(){
  $("#logo").click(function(){
    var homeApplicationId = '';
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(homeApplicationId)){
      ApplicationPortalUtils.loadTopNavigation(homeApplicationId, ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem);
    }
    return false;
  });
  })();
</script>

<div id="environmentNavigation" class="yui-navset yui-navset-top">
  <ul class="yui-nav">
  <li nav="myDash" class="" title=""><a href="#" hidefocus="true"><em>My dashboard</em></a></li><li nav="myApp"><a href="#" hidefocus="true"><em>My applications</em></a></li><li nav="myPermits"><a href="#" hidefocus="true"><em>My permits</em></a></li><li nav="allPermits" class="" title=""><a href="#" hidefocus="true"><em>All permits</em></a></li><li nav="myDetails" class="selected" title="active"><a href="#" hidefocus="true"><em>My Details</em></a></li></ul>
<div class="yui-content"><div style="display: none;"></div><div style="display: none;"></div><div style="display: none;"></div><div style="display: none;"></div><div style="display: block;"></div></div></div>

<script>
   (function(){
     var tabView = new YAHOO.widget.TabView('environmentNavigation');

     // We add an entry under the ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem key to represent the default secondary navigation
     // item (tab) to be displayed for the current top-navigation item ("app"). It will always be the first item in the list.
     var navItemDefaultContent = {};


       navItemDefaultContent[ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem] = {};
       navItemDefaultContent[ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem]['url'] = '\/portal.bg?appian_environment=apps&%24p=67';
       navItemDefaultContent[ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem]['index'] = 0;

       navItemDefaultContent['myDash'] = {};
       navItemDefaultContent['myDash']['url'] = '\/portal.bg?appian_environment=apps&%24p=67';
       navItemDefaultContent['myDash']['index'] = '0';

       navItemDefaultContent['myApp'] = {};
       navItemDefaultContent['myApp']['url'] = '\/portal.bg?appian_environment=apps&%24p=86';
       navItemDefaultContent['myApp']['index'] = '1';

       navItemDefaultContent['myPermits'] = {};
       navItemDefaultContent['myPermits']['url'] = '\/portal.bg?appian_environment=apps&%24p=88';
       navItemDefaultContent['myPermits']['index'] = '2';

       navItemDefaultContent['allPermits'] = {};
       navItemDefaultContent['allPermits']['url'] = '\/portal.bg?appian_environment=apps&%24p=85';
       navItemDefaultContent['allPermits']['index'] = '3';

       navItemDefaultContent['myDetails'] = {};
       navItemDefaultContent['myDetails']['url'] = '\/portal.bg?appian_environment=apps&%24p=53';
       navItemDefaultContent['myDetails']['index'] = '4';

     Environment.Navigation.afterContentLoad = function(content) {
       // #39204: Show main content after we finished loading everything to avoid flickering.
       $("#mainContent").show();
     };

     /**
      * Navigates into a new tab in the designer portal environment.
      *
      * @param {String} navToken The URL identifier corresponding to the secondary navigation item. Optionally it
      *         can also contain the content url to load. The format in the latter case is: url_identifier[;content].
      *         The content url is expected to be properly URL encoded.
      * @param {String} pageId (optional) The URL identifier corresponding to the page to show.
      */
     Environment.Navigation.goTo = function(navToken, pageId) {
       // #37674: the tabView component does not provide a way to get the number of tabs,
       // so try and retrieve the second one. If it does not exist, hide the component.
       if (!tabView.getTab(1)) {
         $('#environmentNavigation').hide();
       }

       var currentState = YAHOO.util.History.getCurrentState(ApplicationPortalUtils.navItemKey);
       if (navToken === currentState) {
         var navConfig = {};
         var contentIndex = navToken.indexOf(';');
         if (contentIndex < 0) {
           navConfig.navItemId = navToken;
         } else {
           navConfig.navItemId = navToken.substring(0, contentIndex);
           navConfig.content = navToken.substring(contentIndex + 1);
         }

         // Check if the nav item is valid. If it's invalid, it will try to default to
         // the application's default nav item.
         if (!navItemDefaultContent[navConfig.navItemId]) {
           if (!navItemDefaultContent['system.defaultitem']) { // The application itself is either invalid or it might not have any nav items.
             // The app doesn't have any content to load, so we manually need to invoke the
             // "afterContentLoad" callback.
             Environment.Navigation.afterContentLoad();
             return;
           }
           var errorCallback = function() {
             asi.alert('The specified page is not available.');
           };
           navConfig.navItemId = 'system.defaultitem';
         }

         tabView.set('activeIndex', navItemDefaultContent[navConfig.navItemId].index);

         if (pageId) {
           backgroundAction('/portal.do?$p=' + pageId, null, errorCallback);
         } else if (!navConfig.content || StringUtils.isBlank(navConfig.content)) {
           backgroundAction(navItemDefaultContent[navConfig.navItemId].url, null, errorCallback);
         } else {
           backgroundAction(navConfig.content, null, errorCallback);
         }
       } else {
         YAHOO.util.History.navigate(ApplicationPortalUtils.navItemKey, navToken);
       }
     };

     $('#environmentNavigation li').click(function(){
       var navItem = this.getAttribute(ApplicationPortalUtils.navItemKey);
       Environment.Navigation.goTo(navItem);
     });
   })();
</script>


<div id="environmentTitlebar">
  <div style="position:relative">
    <div id="inlineConfirmMessage" onclick="STATUS.hide();" title="Click to hide message" class="" style="display: none;">Inline confirmation message text goes here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="pageTitle">My Details</div>
  <div id="pageContext"></div>
  <div id="breadcrumb"></div>
  <div class="links">
    <div id="optionsToggleContainer" style="">
      <a href="#" hidefocus="true">Actions</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pageOptionsMenu" class="yuimenu yui-module yui-overlay" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -9999.41px;"><div class="bd"><ul class="first-of-type"><li class="yuimenuitem first-of-type" id="yui-gen3" groupindex="0" index="0"><a href="#" class="yuimenuitemlabel">Bookmark this page</a></li></ul></div><div class="yui-menu-shadow"></div></div>
</div>

<div id="environmentContent" lasthref="/portal.bg?appian_environment=apps&amp;%24p=53" class="">

  <div class="asiPortalPageHeader"><h1>My Details</h1>

</div>

<div class="asiToolbar" id="portalPageToolbar" style="display: none;">

  <input id="secretPageName" type="hidden" value="My Details">

</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 70%;" id="leftColumn" class="portletColumn"><div id="portletContainer_178">

  <a name="178"></a>
  <div class="portlet portletPlain">
    <div class="portletHeader viewerMode">

      &nbsp;
    </div>

</div>

<div id="portletContainer_224">

  <a name="224"></a>
  <div class="portlet portletPlain">
    <div class="portletHeader viewerMode">

      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="portletBody">
    <div class="portletError" id="portletError_224" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="portletMessage" id="portletMessageBar_224" style="display:none;"></div>

  <div id="miniWebForm_224" class="mini">

  <div id="miniWebContent_224" style="display: none"><p><strong><font size="3"><a href="/suite/process/switchmodeldashboardordetails.bg?processModelId=643&amp;showDashboard=true&amp;appian_environment=" target="fProcess" rel="noopener noreferrer">Update My User Profile</a></font></strong></p>
    <p><em>You can update your user contact details using this function.<br></em></p></div>
      <iframe title="Web channel content" style="width: 100%; height: 35px;" frameborder="0" id="miniWebIframe_224" src="/suite/p_mini/viewMiniContent.do?chid=224&amp;appian_environment=apps"></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="portletContainer_232">
  <a name="232"></a>
  <div class="portlet portletPlain">
    <div class="portletHeader viewerMode">

      &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="portletBody">
      <div class="portletError" id="portletError_232" style="display:none;"></div>
      <div class="portletMessage" id="portletMessageBar_232" style="display:none;"></div>

    <div id="miniWebForm_232" class="mini">

      <div id="miniWebContent_232" style="display: none"><p><strong><font size="3"><a href="https://myminesonline.business.qld.gov.au/suite/startprocess/resetpassword.popup?appian_environment=apps" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Change My User Password</a>&nbsp;</font></strong></p>
        <p><em>You can reset your MyMines Online password using this function.</em><br></p></div>
          <iframe title="Web channel content" style="width: 100%; height: 35px;" frameborder="0" id="miniWebIframe_232" src="/suite/p_mini/viewMiniContent.do?chid=232&amp;appian_environment=apps"></iframe>
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="portletContainer_108">

  <a name="108"></a>
  <div class="portlet portletPlain">
    <div class="portletHeader viewerMode">

      &nbsp;
    </div>

        <div class="portletBody">
            <div class="portletError" id="portletError_108" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div class="portletMessage" id="portletMessageBar_108" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="miniWebForm_108" class="mini">

  <div id="miniWebContent_108" style="display: none"><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><font size="5"><strong>Authorised holder representative (AHR) details <br></strong></font></p>
<hr>

<p></p>
<p></p></div>
  <iframe title="Web channel content" style="width: 100%; height: 59px;" frameborder="0" id="miniWebIframe_108" src="/suite/p_mini/viewMiniContent.do?chid=108&amp;appian_environment=apps"></iframe>
</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div style="float: right; width: 29%;" id="rightColumn" class="portletColumn"><div id="portletContainer_112">

<a name="112"></a>
<div class="portlet portletDefault">
  <div class="portletHeader">

    I want to...
  </div>

      <div class="portletBody">
          <div class="portletError" id="portletError_112" style="display:none;"></div>
          <div class="portletMessage" id="portletMessageBar_112" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="miniWebForm_112" class="mini">

    <div id="miniWebContent_112" style="display: none"><p><a href="mailto:mines_online@dnrm.qld.gov.au" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Contact the helpdesk</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://myminesonline.business.qld.gov.au/help/Default_Left.htm" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Open MyMinesOnline help</a><br></p></div>
    <iframe title="Web channel content" style="width: 100%; height: 30px;" frameborder="0" id="miniWebIframe_112" src="/suite/p_mini/viewMiniContent.do?chid=112&amp;appian_environment=apps"></iframe>
  </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br style="clear: both;">&nbsp;

<div style="clear: both; visibility: hidden;">.</div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    function updateCounter(containers, count) {
      if(count > 0) {
        containers.html("&nbsp;({0})".supplant(count));
      } else {
        containers.html("");
      }
    }

    var tasksCount = parseInt('2');
    var notificationsCount = parseInt('0');

    var tasksSpan = $("#environmentHeader span.taskCount").add("#environmentNavigation span.taskCount");
    var alertsSpan = $("#environmentHeader span.notificationCount").add("#environmentNavigation span.notificationCount");

    updateCounter(tasksSpan, tasksCount);
    updateCounter(alertsSpan, notificationsCount);
  })();
</script>

<div style="clear:both; visibility:hidden;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

</div>

<iframe id="yui-history-iframe" style="display:none;" src="/suite/portal/blank.jsp" title="Background processing frame. No displayed content."></iframe>
<input id="yui-history-field" type="hidden">

<script>
  (function initializeHistory(){
    var initialTopNavViewState = YAHOO.util.History.getBookmarkedState(ApplicationPortalUtils.topNavKey);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(initialTopNavViewState)) {
      // if no bookmarked state is available then use the top-navigation item determined by
      // ApplicationsPortalEntryPoint as the default state; 'system.tasks' is used as last-resource
      // fallback -it would only be used if the requested top-navigation item is invalid or not
      // available; in which case we already present an error page.
      var topNavItemId = 'myminesonline';
      initialTopNavViewState = StringUtils.isBlank(topNavItemId) ? 'system.tasks' : topNavItemId;
    }

    // The registration of the application needs to happen before the registration of the
    // tab navigation. When changing apps, we have to do a "multinavigate" to update
    // both status, the status of the app and the navigation and YUI will trigger
    // both of them. However, we just need to execute the application status change.
    YAHOO.util.History.register(ApplicationPortalUtils.topNavKey, initialTopNavViewState, ApplicationPortalUtils.loadTopNavigation);

    var initialNavItemState = YAHOO.util.History.getBookmarkedState(ApplicationPortalUtils.navItemKey) || ApplicationPortalUtils.defaultNavItem;
    YAHOO.util.History.register(ApplicationPortalUtils.navItemKey, initialNavItemState, function(navId){
      Environment.Navigation.goTo(navId);
    });

    YAHOO.util.History.onReady(function executeWhenPageIsFinishedLoading() {
      // This function gets triggered after login or after a full page refresh.
      // In the first case, there will not be a bookmarked state, we just need to go
      // to the "initialNavItemState".
      // In the second case, there might be a bookmarked state, if so, navigate to
      // that state.
      var bookmarkedTopNavState = YAHOO.util.History.getBookmarkedState(ApplicationPortalUtils.topNavKey);
      if (StringUtils.isBlank(bookmarkedTopNavState)) {
        Environment.Navigation.goTo(initialNavItemState);
      } else {
        ApplicationPortalUtils.loadTopNavigation(bookmarkedTopNavState);
      }
    });

    YAHOO.util.History.initialize("yui-history-field", "yui-history-iframe");
  })();
</script>

<div id="footer">

19.3.151 ©2003-2021 Queensland Government
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.body.onclick= function (evt) {
    evt = evt || event;
    var target = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
    try{ DATETIME.hideAll(target); } catch(e){}
    try { hideAllReportPalettes(target, true); } catch(e){}
    try{ DROPDOWN.hideAll(); } catch(e){}
    try{ if(!(target.id in set('formPropertiesPaneLink','formPropertiesPaneImg'))){$("#formPropertiesPane").hide();}} catch(e){}
  }

  document.onmousedown = function (e) {
    try { DIALOG.pick(e); } catch(e){}
  }

  document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    try { DIALOG.move(e); } catch(e){}
  }

  document.onmouseup = function (e) {
    try { DIALOG.drop(e); } catch(e){}
  }

  document.onmouseover = document.onmouseout = function () {
    window.status = '';
    return true;
  }

  window.onresize = function(){
    if (AUTOCOMPLETE.pointer){ AUTOCOMPLETE.pointer.placeSuggestionGrid(); }
  }

  function hideLayers() {
    try { STATUS.hide(); } catch(e){}
    try { DIALOG.hide(); } catch(e){}
    try { DATETIME.hideAll(); } catch(e){}
    try { PICKER.hideAll(); } catch(e){}
    asi.removeAlert();
  }

  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case  ESC_KEY: hideLayers(); break;
      case  ENTER_KEY:
        try { autoClick(getObject('asiAlertOK')); } catch(e){}
      break;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function onfocus() {
    if ((typeof processModelerLegacy != 'undefined' && processModelerLegacy.closed == true) ||
        (typeof processModelerDesign != 'undefined' && processModelerDesign.closed == true)) {
      if (window.PROCESS_MODEL_ID) {
        backgroundPage("/process/unlockProcessModel.none?processModelId="+window.PROCESS_MODEL_ID);
      } else if (window.PROCESS_ID) {
        backgroundPage("/process/unlockProcessModel.none?processId="+window.PROCESS_ID);
      }
      document.body.onfocus=null;
    }
    if (typeof processModelerLegacy == 'undefined' && typeof processModelerDesign == 'undefined') {
      document.body.onfocus=null;
    }
  }
</script>

<iframe src="javascript:''" id="masterapp" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none;"></iframe><div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div><div class="appian-indicator-message" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"><span class="GE4QWF-BK-"><span class="GE4QWF-BJ-">Working...</span></span> <span class="GE4QWF-BL-">Working...</span></div><div style="position: absolute; height: 1px; width: 1px; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;"><span class="ygtvtm">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvtmh">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvtp">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvtph">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvln">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvlm">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvlmh">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvlp">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvlph">&nbsp;</span><span class="ygtvloading">&nbsp;</span></div></body>
```

Comment: where is your code, what xpath do you use?

Comment: added the xpath

Comment: check is there iframe tag available?

Comment: @Vova sorry but yes there are iframe tags but they are not inside the tags. And they are above it.

Comment: can you share url?

Comment: It requires login. I can share the source code

Comment: @MrAnonymous : is it right html you have posted? there are two `all parrmits` html element?

Comment: @KunduK there were it was done by mistake, but I changed it

Comment: @MrAnonymous : Still I can see two elements all same attribute the HTML you have posted.

Comment: Can you add the code that initializes the WebDriverWait object? Can you also add the code used to initialize your web driver object as well?

Comment: Thank you for being so responsive to our questions. Problems with Selenium are hard to track down. If it helps, have a look at [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405792/3092298)

Comment: @MrAnonymous : Are you using headless mode? is your page fully loaded before you grab the `page_source`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt added the webdriver initialization part. I have posted the page source at the bottom, please have a look.

Comment: @KunduK I am not using headless mode and yes the page is fully loaded I am using time 20s to wait and by then the page is loaded, I even tried running the first part as the page is loaded and after waiting for for a couple of seconds I execute the other i.e locating the 'All permits' element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to the `<frame>` first, and then find the element.

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id("fContent")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
xpath = "//div[@id='environmentNavigation']//li/a[contains(., 'All permits')]"
tab = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))

tab.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to click with JavaScript:

```
import time

time.sleep(3)
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@nav="allPermits"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```